# Problema ao setor setImageResource

Tags: php, javascript, java, c#, android

Olá, tenho um projeto ao qual carrego imagens drawable para um ListView, o problema é que quando rodo o projeto não aparece as imagens sentadas, alguém pode me ajudar a encontrar o erro?

LAYOUT main_activity

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lstdados"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:dividerHeight="7dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

LAYOUT itemlistview

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgfoto"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTitulo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Titulo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textDetalhes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Descripicion" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

CLASSE MAIN

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ListView listaDados;
ArrayList <Dados> lista;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

    listaDados  =(ListView)findViewById( R.id.lstdados );
    lista = new ArrayList<Dados>(  );

    lista.add( new Dados( "Blusa",1,R.drawable.gratis,"verao" ) );
    lista.add( new Dados( "Casaco",2,R.drawable.carregarfoto1,"Inverno" ) );
    lista.add( new Dados( "Calça",3,R.drawable.camera,"Longa" ) );

    Adaptador miadaptador = new Adaptador( getApplicationContext(),lista );

    listaDados.setAdapter( miadaptador );
 }
```

}

CLASSE DADOS

public class Dados {

```
private int Id;
private String Titulo;
private String Detalhe;
private int Imagem;

public Dados(String detalhe, int id, int imagem, String titulo) {
    Id = id;
    Titulo = titulo;
    Detalhe = detalhe;
    this.Imagem = imagem;
}

public int getId() {
    return Id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    Id = id;
}

public String getTitulo() {
    return Titulo;
}

public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
    Titulo = titulo;
}

public String getDetalhe() {
    return Detalhe;
}

public void setDetalhe(String detalhe) {
    Detalhe = detalhe;
}

public int getImagem() {
    return Imagem;
}

public void setImagem(int imagem) {
    Imagem = imagem;
}
```

}

CLASSE ADAPTADOR

public class Adaptador extends BaseAdapter{
    Context contexto;
    List ListaObjetos;
    private ImageView img;
    private TextView titulo;
    private TextView detalhe;

```
public Adaptador(Context contexto, List<Dados> listaObjetos) {
    this.contexto = contexto;
    ListaObjetos = listaObjetos;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ListaObjetos.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return ListaObjetos.get( position );
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return ListaObjetos.get( position ).getId();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vista = convertView;

    LayoutInflater inflate = LayoutInflater.from( contexto );
    vista = inflate.inflate(R.layout.itemlistview, null);

    img = (ImageView) vista.findViewById( R.id.imgfoto );
    titulo =(TextView) vista.findViewById( R.id.textTitulo );
    detalhe =(TextView) vista.findViewById( R.id.textDetalhes );

    titulo.setText(ListaObjetos.get( position ).getTitulo().toString());
    detalhe.setText(ListaObjetos.get( position ).getDetalhe().toString());
    img.setImageResource( ListaObjetos.get( position ).getImagem() );

    return  vista;
}
```

}

Os textos aparecem no ListView mais as imagens não.